# How to access widgets' properties dynamically in python + kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am adding widgets dynamically in kivy using python and would like to be able to access the properties like id, text etc.

```
self.ids.grid.cols = 4
        for i in range(12):
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(id = str(i+1), text = 'Teste'))
```

I tried

```
print(self.ids.grid.1)
```

or

```
print(self.ids.grid.'1')    



self.ids.grid.cols = 4
        for i in range(12):
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(id = str(i+1), text = 'Teste'))
```

I want to be able to write data to a database, but first I need to access the widget

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop to access the `id` and `text`.

```
for child in reversed(self.ids.grid.children):
    if isinstance(child, TextInput):
        print(f"child: id={child.id}, text={child.text}")
```

## py: id versus kv: id

### py - `id`

- The value of `id` created in Python script is a string.
- An `id` created in Python script is not stored in the `self.ids` dictionary type property.
- One cannot use this `id` (e.g. `id='ti'`) to reference the object and its attributes e.g. `self.ids.ti` or `self.ids['ti']`

### kv - `id`

- The value of `id` created in kv file is ***not*** a string.
- An `id` declared in kv file is stored in the `self.ids` dictionary type property.
- One can use this `id` (e.g. `id: ti`) to reference the object and its attributes e.g. `self.ids.ti` or `self.ids['ti']`

## References

[Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> When assigning a value to `id`, remember that the value isn’t a
>   string. There are no quotes:
>
> good -> `id: value`,
>
> bad -> `id: 'value'`

Answer (score 0):

I usually added them into a dict or list, whichever is more convenient.
This of course means to add a new list in the constructor

```
self.text_inputs = []
```

And then adding the widgets to it

```
self.ids.grid.cols = 4
    for i in range(12):
        text_input = TextInput(id = str(i+1), text = 'Teste')
        self.text_inputs.append(text_input)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(text_input)
```

And then easily access it with

```
print(self.text_inputs[1].text)
```